# Comparing dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `DateTime` column named `EXP_Date` which contains date like this :

```
2014-07-13 00:00:00.000
```

I want to compare them, like this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DB
WHERE ('2014-07-15' - EXP_DATE)  > 1
```

I expect to see the number of customers who have their services expired for over a month.

I know this query wouldn't give me the correct answer, the best way was if I separate the Year / Month / Day into three columns, but isn't any other way to compare them as they are?

Comment: What datatype are you using in your table? And which **version** of SQL Server (2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014) ??

Comment: Data Type= datetime  version=2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM DB
 where EXP_DATE < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: For some people it might. I like this one better.

Comment: Yup, that's just a point of view, indeed... Was just wondering if there was a specific reason ;)

Comment: what if i want to see the number of customers who have been at least 2 months expired and not more than 5 months, 2 < (exp_date - today) <5

Comment: @RmanEdv: `where EXP_DATE < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) AND EXP_DATE >= DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM DB
 where  DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) > EXP_DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT COUNT(EXPIRE)FROM 
 (Select CASE WHEN  EXP_DATE < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS EXPIRE FROM DB
  )tt
```

Comment: did you test it ?  it doesn't work, this error : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.  actually it is very useful to have that case

Answer (score 2):

Another way using **DATEDIFF**

---

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY  --I like to use "dateformat"

SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM DB
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY,@EXP_DATE,GETDATE())) >= 30 --Remember, instead "Day" you can use week, month, year, etc
```

**Syntax**: DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
*Depart*: year, quarter, month, day, week...

For more information you can visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

---